# How many ways can we write a word of 4 letters from the group of {1,2,3,4} without the sequence 12 and 23?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, inclusion-exclusion, combinatorics-on-words

How many ways can we write a word of 4 letters from the group of {1,2,3,4} without sequence 12 and 23?
the options are:

1. 16
   2.256
   3.172
   4.24

I think we can repeat on the same letter so I tried to this:
count all of the words without any constraint: $4^4$
count the illegal words and then to do: $4^4$- illegal--> to get what I want.
but I didn't get any of these options.
thank you for your help!

Comment: To clarify, is $1244$ a valid sequence since although it contained $12$ it did not contain $23$?  In other words, must it contain both $12$ *and* $23$ to be considered invalid or must it merely contain at least one of them?

Comment: You will want to count the number which have $12$ at least once.  It could have been a number of the form $12**$ or $*12*$ or $**12$ (*noting that $1212$ was in both the first and last category simultaneously*).  Similarly you may want to count with $23$.  You may also want to be counting those which simultaneously have $12$ and $23$ which might have been of the form $123*$, $1223$, $*123$ or $2312$.

Comment: I think that it must merely contain at least one of them

Comment: and I tried that and get 150 options. maybe I do something wrong somewhere

Comment: Where is this question from?

Comment: from exam before 2 years at my course

Answer (score 2):

In retrospect, this response is nothing but a re-hash of the comments of J Moravitz, which preceded it.

---

Hints:

When employing [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) in this problem, things to note:

1. Superficially, you would surmise that the number of ways that the sequence "12" can occur **at least once** is $\binom{3}{1} \times 4^2 = 48.$  This is wrong, since it over-counts the sequence "1212".  Therefore, the correct enumeration here is $47.$
2. When enumerating the number of ways that the sequences "12" and "23" can both occur, for the **add-back**, re Inclusion-Exclusion, you have to count separately : "X123", "123X", "1223", and "2312".

Comment: thank you very much!! I didn't recognize the over count of 1212.